# Ionic 6. App crashes only when installed from play store

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play

Whenever I build the application locally it works works fine, even with --prod flag. But with the .aab bundle uploaded to Google play store any instance of the application downloaded from there is crashing. Below is the Ionic info of the application.

**Ionic Info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.29
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 25 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.5.0) : 1.2.2

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/abhishyam/android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.19.0 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.9
   OS                : Linux 5.4
```

**Plugins used:**

```
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 3.2.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.12 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-chooser 1.3.1 "Chooser"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-enable-multidex 0.2.0 "Enable Multidex"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.6 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 13.0.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.7.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.4.1 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-unique-device-id2 2.0.0 "UniqueDeviceID"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 6.0.0 "Cordova SQLite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova-support-google-services 1.4.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

**Stacktrace of Crash Report from Playstore**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:1296)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6876)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:269)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2010)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: a:
  at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader (ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
  at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader (ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
  at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries (ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked (LoadedApk.java:892)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader (LoadedApk.java:991)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources (LoadedApk.java:1248)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext (ContextImpl.java:2616)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext (ContextImpl.java:2608)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6783)

java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:1296)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6876)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:269)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2010)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication (AppComponentFactory.java:76)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication (CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:1156)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:1288)
```

Unable to debug this issue for a week. I tried to check if there is a conflict with any of the plugins that are being used. But was not able to figure it out. How do I fix this?

Comment: What Plugins Are you using? do you have all permissions ?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I have updated the question with pulgins used. I have all user permissions.